# Sphinx Autodoc output order

Tags: python-sphinx, private-members, autodoc

Is it possible to change the order of the output generated with Sphinx AutoDoc?

In particular, I am including private members, using the `:private-members:` directive. 
What I want is the private members to appear *last* in the output and not first which is the default, caused by alphabetic order and the "_" character coming before "A".

Comment: Reading the documentation, I found this option https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#confval-autodoc_member_order Does that do what you want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just as @Steve Piercy mentioned, you can set the order using the config value `autodoc_member_order`. To get the desired behaviour, just add `autodoc_member_order = 'bysource'` to your `conf.py`. This will make your documentations order the same as your source order.

Comment: Is there a way to change the behavior on a module-by-module basis? Or even class-by-class?